# Why the php timestamp is different from mysql UNIX_TIMESTAMP for a future date?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

This is really strange for me.

I tried: 
`<?php echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); ?>`

It returned: **1351498120**.

Also, when i ran this query:  `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())` ,

it returned the same result: **1351498120**.

But when i tried: `<?php echo strtotime(date("2012-10-29 18:00:00")); ?>`

It returns: **1351533600**.

Whereas, if i run this query: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-29 18:00:00')`,

it returns: **1351513800**

**Now my question is:** why the timestamps of php and mysql are same for current date, but different for future dates? Is there a way to compare them for future dates?

(NOTE: I have UTC as default timezone in php)

Comment: In case your MySQL server runs on a unix/linux system you might be interested in updating your time zone info (usually part of the "normal" os update system, e.g. timezone.rpm) and then use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html to refresh MySQL's time zone table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a **5.5 hour difference** between the 2, which indicates it is a timezone issue, on either end.
The MySql Server's Timezone could be configured differently.

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

can be used to set timezone for the current session.
Check **[MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)**

Comment: @sephoy 1351513800 - 1351533600 = 19800; 19800/3600 = `-5.5`, which makes sense because India is `GMT - 5:30`

Comment: Ok, I wrote this at the top of my page: mysql_query("SET time_zone =  '+00:00'"); Now timestamps for both php and mysql are coming same.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the default time zone

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I tried: date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); but it is still same.